# How to get reference of View in Controller

Tags: ember.js

I am using Ember 1.0pre and following Ember suggested [application structure](http://emberjs.com/guides/outlets/#toc_ember-application-structure) (Using Router).
For form validation, I want to call **$('form').valid()** method on Button click. 
So I have following method in my view

```
validate: function(){
  return this.$('form').valid()
}
```

Action in template file:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn" {{action doSaveSettings this}}>Save Changes</button>
```

and **doSaveSettings** method is in Controller. 
How can I get instance of view in controller, for calling validate method?

**EDIT:**
In controller, this.view is null. I have put {{debugger}} in template and this refers to 
<App.XyzController:ember1062> and this.view is null.

Answer (score 1):

The default target of actions have been changed from the view to the router in ember 0.9.8.1 (I believe). To set the target to the view you need to override it like this

```
 <button type="submit" class="btn" {{action doSaveSettings target="view"}}>Save Changes</button>
```

edit: Your controllers should not know about the view.

Comment: so, what do you suggest for validation? How can I achieve it without calling custom method in controller (on click)

Comment: Also, when I change target, action will be called on View, which is I think not appropriate i think.

Comment: I have heard that the ember team have put off adding a validations framework until later. I would implement validations on the controller rather than the view, as the controller is supposed to manage the data. Then your validations are preserved even if you change the view of it. Here is an example of a validation that someone has integrated into the view: https://gist.github.com/3301728

Comment: I checked out gist your provided in above comment. I understood that code, but still It is not explaining how we can decide whether every field (view) is valid or still there are some validation issues. In controller. I hope you got my point.

Comment: Actually, upon further thought, I would probably implement the validations on the model as a function which returns an array of errors. So I would have a save action that targets the router, within that action I would call controller.save function which would then call the model.validate function. If that returns errors (an array) I would set an errors property on the controller that the view would show and have the function return return false. If the return value of controller.save were false I would abort the save action.

Answer (score 0):

In ember the purpose of a view is only i repeat is only to handle events or to create reusable components
i would not suggest this since there is always a reason why views are not meant to be accessed from controller and its good to follow it, however if you really do want to use it you could do the below two ways:
I dont know if u r using ember-cli or ember but the logic is same. The answer however is for ember-cli

```
//Inside appname/controller/your-conroller.js

import reqdView from 'appname/views/your-view';

//Lets assume u want to call a function called validate inside view
//Add this statement inside the controller to run the validate function

reqdView.prototype.validate();

OR

var reqdViewInst = new reqdView();
reqdViewInst.validate();
```

If you want to validate the view then do the validation inside didInsertElement

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
didInsertElement:function()
{
  this.validate(); 
},
validate:function()
{
//do your validation
}
});
```

OR

```
export default Ember.View.extend({
eventManager: Ember.Object.create({
    didInsertElement:function(event, view)
    {
      view.validate(); 
    }
  }),

    validate:function()
    {
    //do your validation
    }
    });
```